# How to specify behavior of Java BufferedImage resize: need min for pixel rows instead of averaging

Tags: java, user-interface, image-processing, bufferedimage

I would like to resize a Java BufferedImage, making it smaller vertically but without using any type of averaging, so that if a pixel-row is "blank" (white) in the source image, there will be a white pixel-row in the corresponding position of the destination image: the "min" operation. The default algorithms (specified in [getScaledInstance](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)) do not allow me a fine-grained enough control. I would like to implement the following logic:

```
for each pixel row in the w-pixels wide destination image, d = pixel[w]
   find the corresponding j pixel rows of the source image, s[][] = pixel[j][w]
   write the new line of pixels, so that d[i] = min(s[j][i]) over all j, i
```

I have been reading on [RescaleOp](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html), but have not figured out how to implement this functionality -- it is admittedly a weird type of scaling. Can anyone provide me pointers on how to do this? In the worse case, I figure I can just reserve the destination ImageBuffer and copy the pixels following the pseudocode, but I was wondering if there is better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RescaleOp methods include a parameter called RenderingHints. There is a hint called `KEY_INTERPOLATION` that decides the color to use when scaling an image.

If you use the value `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` for the KEY_INTERPOLATION, Java will use the original colors, rather than using some type of algorithm to recalculate the new colors.

So, instead of white lines turning to gray or some mix of color, you'll get either white lines, or you won't get any lines at all. It all depends on the scaling factor, and if it's an even or odd row. For example, if you are scaling by half, then each 1 pixel horizontal line has at least a 50% change of appearing in the new image. However, if the white lines were two pixels in height, you'd have a 100% chance of the white line appearing.

This is probably the closest you're going to get besides writing your own scaling method. Unfortunately, I don't see any other hints that might help further.

To implement your own scaling method, you could create a new class that implements the `BufferedImageOp` interface, and implement the `filter()` method. Use `getRGB()` and `setRGB()` on the BufferedImage object to get the pixels from the original image and set the pixels on the new image.

Comment: You are probably right - I do not think there is any better way than implementing my own BufferedImageOp. Thanks!